Blender Select Faces
enter image description here
enter image description here
Hi! I am new to Blender and I'm trying to build my first object, a washing-machine. I am trying to hollow out just the drum of the washer, but when I removed the front face of the cylinder, the front face of the washer is still there. I added 2 photos for reference to my question, how can I do a face-select on just the blue part I have scribbled over so I can remove just that face? Thanks in advance!
I tried right-clicking and trying "subdivide", "split", "separate". I also tried watching multiple tutorials. I tried the knife feature to cut out the circle. I'm at a loss!

you want the blender stack exchange not Stack overflow which is for programming questions.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/

I'm a blender noob, but an easy problem in blender to run into is accidentally making duplicate faces/vertices. often happens when you accidentally extrude something with no offset. so you might have deleted the duplicate face but not the original.

@DavidSullivan thank you! I am a developer so I wasn't sure where to put my question. Thanks again!
